# WPF datagrid Header for Grouping

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

This is the image i'm getting while grouping using WPF DataGrid. This link is got from       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. I need Group Headers here.

```
           Eg:   Project      Count          
                 Project1     4              
                 Project2     5              
                 Project3     5
```

How can i make this?
The image shown in link need to be checked to solve my problem. I need all as the link + One head as i mentioned.(I made the same image for upload.Since i don't have enough reputation i'm unable to add images)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LINQ you can do

```
dataGrid.dataSource = from tb in yourDataBase.table
                      group tb by theFieldyouWant into g
                      select new {Prjoect = g.Key, ProjectCount=g.Count()};
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. But the requirement is not like that. In this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.100%29.aspx we can see they are grouping.

Upto that its fine. On group i need heading like "Project      count". How can i achive this is my query.

Thanking you

Comment: In the example you gave, you said that you want one Header called Project and the Other Count.. no?

Comment: I got where you got confused. Sorry for lacking clarity in question. The image shown in link need to be checked to solve my problem. I need all as the link + One head as i mentioned.(I made the same image for upload.Since i don't have enough reputation i'm unable to add images)

Comment: you can upload the image to some server and link to it

Comment: so you want the all table headers + Count? like
projectName,TaskName,DueDate,Complete,Count ?

Comment: No, In the similar colour(Blue) I need two texts "Project  Count". So when all span is minimized state it will seem as table as i shown in question. Simply showing Project1,4   Project2,5  Project3,5 is meaningless. This is a sample work only. When i goes to real project(Eg: Employee). Simply showing
A   10000   200  100
  Its detail span    
B   20000   300  500
  Its detail span 

Is meaning less. I need Heading "Employee Name    Salary   Tax   TA"

Comment: Means Like the group on same look and feal i need one heading

Comment: Other wise any other way to handle my problem is also hearlty welcome. For example. Groups will on datagrid at first, Inside each group another datagrid contains details also acceptable for me

Comment: So correct me if I wrong (again.. hehe) You want to create A header like the dark blue in the image, and after it another header , like the light blue and then show the datagrid? 

I think they create those datagrid dynamically..

Comment: Yes. What you understood is right. They are acheiving this through <DataGrid.GroupStyle> in xaml. I need a heading for each groupstyle

Comment: take a look at those links 
http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html and
http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/applying-groupstyle-in-datagrid/
the second one would help you...